# IP Routing: How to route a secondary IP address on a Host-Only network

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I have a standard static IP address and I added the secondary IP address via `IP addr` command. For reference, the set up I have is two virtual machines running Linux and my intentions are to bind some arbitrary IP address to the network interface on machine A and be able to contact and ping that IP address from machine B. For this I am using virtual box with both of these machines in a host-only network and vbox ethernet.

My primary question is how to route the arbitrary IP address so that it is reachable from a different machine on the same host-only network.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04, sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Given the distro and version of linux...

There are some things to get out of the way... I understand you are using two virtual machines on an ethernet network. The command 
 `IP addr`
  is a temporary IP address, which will reset upon reboot. 
 Try to edit with privs: 
 /etc/network/interfaces and add your new interface in the first machine as a new block: 
 *Example*
 `auto eth0:1`
`iface eth0:1 inet static` 
`address 192.168.0.1`
`gateway 192.168.0.254`
`netmask 255.255.255.0`
 (*EDIT*: This is proper format of the block, only an example I'm not sure what your ethernet device is called on each virtual machine or server. Could be *eth0*, *enp0s2* etc depends on distro + BIOS too)
 
 Now if you don't care about that it's fine just understand if it reboots it will reset second IP address.
 It also is dependent for the NIC of the virtual machine and depends on the virtual setup configuration.
 Select Virtual Machine settings and select NAT for virtual NIC configuration. Then go back to settings and select options to enable guest isolation and VMCI. This will allow you to ping virtual machines in your network. I also believe the MAC is a way to resolve IP addresses, so the network MAC of each machine's ethernet must be *special* due to the arp protocol. This might just be an issue with WLAN setups though (concerning wireless network MAC similarity that causes issues in arp protocols not being able to resolve IP addresses properly). 
 I do think virtual box might require the "guest addition" update on each machine... As VMware is different and just requires the tools installation.